# JavaFx moving images

Tags: java, javafx, sprite, game-physics

Hello all so I'm creating a simple 2D game and so far I've had a bit of a nightmare trying to get things to communicate with each other. So far I have a 'main menu', 'game grid' and a image showing on the grid. I'm now tackling the movement off it but I can't seem to get it working.

`application.package`

`Level.class`

```
package application;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Level {

// private static Array[] level1;
// private WarehouseKeeper warehouse;
private static ImageView image1 = ImageLoader.showWareHouseImage();
private static final int KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA = 2;

public static void runLevel1(Stage theStage) {

    // ImageView image = new ImageView((Element)
    // ImageLoader.wareHouseImage);

    // WarehouseKeeper warehouse = new
    // WarehouseKeeper(ImageLoader.wareHouseImage);

    Group root = new Group();

    int columnAmount = 12;
    int rowAmount = 12;

    GridPane gameGrid = new GridPane();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnAmount; i++) {
        ColumnConstraints columnn = new ColumnConstraints(45);
        gameGrid.getColumnConstraints().add(columnn);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowAmount; i++) {

        RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints(45);
        gameGrid.getRowConstraints().add(row);
    }

    gameGrid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-grid-lines-visible:true");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, (columnAmount * 40) + 66, (rowAmount * 40) + 66, Color.WHITE);

    image(root, gameGrid);

    moveWareHouse(scene, createKeeper());

    theStage.setScene(scene);

    theStage.show();

}

private static void image(Group root, GridPane gameGrid) {

    // ImageLoader.wareHouseImage;

    /*
     * ImageView wareHouse = new ImageView(); wareHouse.setFitHeight(45);
     * wareHouse.setFitWidth(45);
     * 
     * Image image1 = ImageLoader.showWareHouseImage();
     * wareHouse.setImage(image1);
     */

    ImageView image1 = ImageLoader.showWareHouseImage();

    final HBox picture = new HBox();
    picture.getChildren().add(image1);

    gameGrid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    // gameGrid.getChildren().add(wareHouse);
    gameGrid.add(picture, 7, 9);

    root.getChildren().add(gameGrid);

}

private static WarehouseKeeper createKeeper() {

    final WarehouseKeeper keeper = new WarehouseKeeper(image1);

    return keeper;
}

private static void moveWareHouse(Scene scene, final WarehouseKeeper keeper) {

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            switch (event.getCode()) {

            case W:
                keeper.setyPosition(keeper.getyPosition() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                break;
            case D:
                keeper.setxPosition(keeper.getxPosition() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                break;
            case A:
                keeper.setyPosition(keeper.getyPosition() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                break;
            case S:
                keeper.setxPosition(keeper.getxPosition() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
   }
}
```

`WarehouseKeeper.class` extends ImageLoader.

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class WarehouseKeeper extends ImageLoader {

private Image playerImage;
private ImageView image;
private int speed;
private double xPosition;
private double yPosition;

public WarehouseKeeper(ImageView wareHouseImage) {

    super(wareHouseImage);

    this.speed = speed;
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
    this.yPosition = yPosition;
    this.wareHouseImage.relocate(xPosition, yPosition);

}

public void updateUI() {

    wareHouseImage.relocate(xPosition, yPosition);

}

public double getCenterX() {

    return xPosition * 0.5;

}

public double getCenterY() {

    return yPosition * 0.5;

}

public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(int speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public double getxPosition() {
    return xPosition;
}

// one of the ideas i had
public void setxPosition(double xPosition) {
    this.xPosition = xPosition.setTranslateX(1.0);
}

public double getyPosition() {
    return yPosition;
}

public void setyPosition(double d) {
    this.yPosition = d + 1.0;
}

public void setTranslateY(double yPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    yPosition = yPosition + 2.0;

  }
}
```

`ImageLoader.class`

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

protected ImageView wareHouseImage;
private Object diamondImage;
private Object wallImage;
private Object mapImage;
private Object crateImage;

public ImageLoader(ImageView wareHouseImage) {

    this.wareHouseImage = showWareHouseImage();

}

public ImageView getWareHouseImage() {
    return wareHouseImage;
}

public void setWareHouseImage(Image wareHouseImage) {
    this.wareHouseImage = showWareHouseImage();
}

public static ImageView showWareHouseImage() {

    ImageView wareHouse = new ImageView();
    wareHouse.setFitHeight(45);
    wareHouse.setFitWidth(45);

    Image wareHouseImage = new Image("application/warehouse.png");
    wareHouse.setImage(wareHouseImage);

    return wareHouse;

}

public Object getDiamondImage() {

    return diamondImage;

}

public void setDiamondImage(Object diamondImage) {

    this.diamondImage = diamondImage;

}

public Object getWallImage() {

    return wallImage;

}

public void setWallImage(Object wallImage) {

    this.wallImage = wallImage;

}

public Object getMapImage() {

    return mapImage;

}

public void setMapImage(Object mapImage) {

    this.mapImage = mapImage;

}

public Object getCrateImage() {

    return crateImage;

}

public void setCrateImage(Object crateImage) {

    this.crateImage = crateImage;

    }
}
```

Comment: when you call your keyboard commands you are using `object.xPosition` have you tried using `object.setLayoutX = value` , also just to note you have are using functions to try and return a value that you could get without needing to put it in a function, for example `case W:
                keeper.setyPosition(keeper.getyPosition() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                break;`
could just be `case W:
                keeper.setyPosition(keeper.getLayoutY() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                break;` no function required.

Comment: Thankyou very much for both of the replies by the way, very kind of you. 

Where would you recommend i place the object.setLayoutX = value method?

Comment: you will need to put them in your level class, as that is where the WarehouseKeeper object is instantized (when it is given a place to go and what Node it needs to be one) it is possible to send the command to another class but to keep it neat your better off just doing it in the same class that it is instantized in, if you read my Answer below, you have it mostly correct you just need to change your keylisteners to use the instantized object in your level Class.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help so far, you are the best!

I can't seem to get it working though, did by any chance get the image to move?

Comment: just double checking your code, you can try parsing the Stage to the moveWareHouse function rather than the scene and put the key listener on the Stage, as that is the global container and that is where it should listen for keypresses. Also be aware it is also good practice to consume the keypress as well using in your case `event.consume();` this will make sure it doesn't do it doesn't do anything erratic afterwards. Just for diagnostic purposes, It might be worth putting a `System.out.println("*direction here* arrow pressed")` message in there to confirm that it is receiving the event.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice, added the println on the methods :) 
i had a try and it's still not working, seems to not like theStage having an event listener on it aswell.

Comment: Hi Steve, if you have time I would like to move this to a chat, might be easier.

Comment: you're amazing already. That would be fab. What would be the best way of contacting you?

Comment: if we keep chatting it should ask to move this to Chat.

Comment: nevermind, join this chat and we can talk there. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135908/discussion-between-travisf-and-mouseevent

Comment: hey Travis apparently i can't use the chatroom due to my reputation

Comment: Ok, does your function still look like this `private static void moveWareHouse(Scene scene, final WarehouseKeeper keeper) {` or does it look like `private static void moveWareHouse(Stage theStage, final WarehouseKeeper keeper) {` and the function caller should look like this `moveWareHouse(theStage, createKeeper());` rather than `moveWareHouse(scene, createKeeper());` the other issue is you are asking for the code `switch (event.getCode()) {` this returns a hexadecimal version of the key that was pressed but you are using switches for the physical character.

Comment: what you want is `switch (event.getCharacter()) {`

Comment: It is giving me an error 
"The method setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){}) is undefined for the type Stage" 

and the cases cannot be resolved to a variable
"W cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: I presume you update `scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {` to `theStage.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {`

Comment: alright, try `theStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
            event.consume();
            /* put switch event here */
        });`
The reason is because the stage does not have a function defined for it for `onKeyPress` but you can define one by filtering the event.

Comment: Thankyou again for the reply. It is compiling now, my problem now however is getting the keeper to show on the grid so the movement can work as i noticed i was only add the image to the GridPane and not the keeper.But apparently that seems to be fairly difficult.

Comment: Yup, I think you may be over complicating that issue, in your public WarehouseKeeper class, you have a public function called WarehouseKeeper (I would recommend changing that function name) I would recommend building the entire object that you would like the main class (level1) to have an control, then in level1 you can call and create a warehouseKeeper through `final WarehouseKeeper wHK = new WarehouseKeeper.warehouseKeeper();` then parse that wHK to the keyEvent handler rather than it making one.

Comment: so the warehouseKeeper function in the WarehouseKeeper class could return a group that is complete with image and everything that it needs, to build the keeper, instead of using `final WarehouseKeeper` you would use `final Group wHK = new WarehouseKeeper.warehouseKeeper();` then you can add that group to your level1 root (which I would also recommend is not a group it should be some sort of Pane a StackPane should suffice for your case) this way you can parse the x and y pos directly to the new object from the key events.

Comment: just in case that is a bit convoluted something like:

`public Group warehouseKeeper(ImageView warehouseImage) {
Group tempGroup;
/* create entire keeper image here and add to tempGroup here */
return tempGroup;
}`

and in level1
`final Group wHK = WarehouseKeeper.warehouseKeeper();
root.getChildren().add(wHK);
moveWarehouse(theStage,wHK);`

and on the moveWarehouse: `protected moveWarehouse(Stage stage, Group wHK) { /* put the rest of your current code for movement here /* }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with your understanding of how the object orientated JavaFX works, the object may be created by the WareHouseKeeper and ImageLoader class, but the object was instantized on the level class, meaning if you instantized the object on the level class it has to be moved within the level class. For example what you have is

```
    private static void moveWareHouse(Scene scene, final WarehouseKeeper keeper) {

scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

        switch (event.getCode()) {

        case W:
            keeper.setyPosition(keeper.getyPosition() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        case D:
            keeper.setxPosition(keeper.getxPosition() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        case A:
            keeper.setyPosition(keeper.getyPosition() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        case S:
            keeper.setxPosition(keeper.getxPosition() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        }
    }
});
}
```

As the object has been passed to the function you would only need to move it directly from within the level class and not from the other Classes, so this would be changed to

```
    private static void moveWareHouse(Stage theStage, Group wHK) {

        theStage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
        e.consume();

        switch (e.getCharacter()) {

        case W:
            keeper.setLayoutY(keeper.getLayoutY() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        case D:
            keeper.setLayoutX(keeper.getLayoutX() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        case A:
            keeper.setLayoutY(keeper.getLayoutY() + KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        case S:
            keeper.setLayoutX(keeper.getLayoutX() - KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
            break;
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
I also noticed you have the Scene parsed as the key listener this would require you to click on the scene (to give it focus) before it will listen to the keys, if you set the stage as the key listener no matter where you click it will always be the root focus and always listening for keys.

**EDITED FURTHER**
As I mentioned in our conversation up the top, your better off creating the entirety of the WarehouseKeeper in your WarehouseKeeper class and instantizing it into your main class (level1) this way the control of the object is within the level1 but level1 does not have all the code to create it (so if you need to modify the creation of it later or use it again you can call more of them by just creating a new instance of it and adding it to the scene) for example.

```
public final Group warehouseKeeper(ImageView image) {
    Group tempGroup;
    /* insert necessary code here to add image to group and anything else you want in the group */
    return tempGroup;
}
```

Then you can instantize it to level1 by just calling

```
final Group wHK = new WarehouseKeeper.warehouseKeeper();
wHK.setLayoutX(/*some init val */);
wHK.setLayoutY(/*some init val */);
root.getChildren().add(wHK);
```